# dojo's event.preventDefault() not working on dojo 1.8 version

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am upgrading the DOJO from 1.4 to 1.8 version. Now, I defined the dojo acccordian widget.I need to stop expanding Accordian widget at the onclick event.

when we used the dojo version 1.4 it worked and , We used the following snippet to stop the onclick event.

Template like below :

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" style="height: 300px;" onclick="onClickHandler">
```

Js like Below:

```
function onClickHandler(evt){
    dojo.stopEvent(evt);
}
```

Got stucked on the following problem on 1.8 Dojo version :

As per the dojo official website https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/stopEvent.html# , they are reporting the dojo.stopEvent() deplrecated.we need to use evt.preventDefault() and evt.stopPropagation() instead.

When I tried the onclickhandler like below , its not stopping the onclick event.

```
function onClickHandler(evt){
    //dojo.stopEvent(evt);
    evt.preventDefault(); //Instead of the stopEvent
    evt.stopPropagation();
}
```

I cannot figure out the problem. Both Chrome and Firefox don't fire any error or exception, so as per my knowledge, no syntax errors.

I tried to 'return false' instead of above mentioned preventDefault & stopPropagation as well.even though its not stopping the onclick event of accordian pane.

Please help me to resolve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, add an `id` to your `accordionContainer` and remove the onclickHandler  us on event instead .

```
<div id="accordionContainer_1" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" style="height: 300px;">
```

After use the following code :

```
require(["dijit/registry","dojo/ready","dojo/_base/array"],
    function(registry,ready,array){
       ready(function(){
            var accordionContainer = registry.byId("accordionContainer_1");
            array.forEach(accordionContainer.getChildren(), function(childPane) { 
                // set click on title event as empty function 
                childPane._buttonWidget._onTitleClick = function(){};
                // set also keyboard keyDwon(up) on title event as empty function  
                childPane._buttonWidget._onKeyPress = function(){};
            });
       }
    }
});
```

So now when the page is loaded , your `accordionPane` inside the `accordionContainer_1` `AcordionContainer` are disabled from slieUp(Down) .

and this is done by assigning an empty function to the _onTitleClick and _onKeyPress (pane->_buttonWidget->_onTitleClick function ...)

IF you want to enble or disable the event on demand you can follow 
[My sample in GitHUB](https://github.com/bRIMOs/ArrocrdionDisableSample) , run the file inside a web server .

Comment: Thanks for your reply bRIMOs.I tried the event.stop method from dojo/_base/event .Eventhough its not stopping the onclick event.   Is there any other event stop function is available to acheive this ?

Comment: Just a question, have you a `dijit/layout/AccordionPane` inside that div , 
and do you want to stop the slidedown and slideup of these `AccordionPanes` !

Comment: Yeah ,exactly.I want to stop the slidedown and slide up accordion pane inside the accordian container.

Comment: All the accordion Or just on demand ?
I think I have some suggestions .

Comment: All accordian panes i need to disable the Onclick event.

Comment: does it help ! or you need more explanation ?